# Cannot find /data/data/package.name/databases

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to copy a SQLite database from assets/ into the app's databases/ directory, but as I'll show you below, I keep getting null pointer exceptions. Below is some potentially relevant Logcat and code:

```
   [ 11-24 21:51:19.694  1652:0x67e E/AndroidRuntime ]
    FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at net.xx.wildedibles.full.common.DataBaseHelper.<init>(DataBaseHelper.java:27)
        at net.xx.wildedibles.full.common.DBAdapter.<init>(DBAdapter.java:21)
        at net.xx.wildedibles.full.intro.LoadingFragment$LoadingTask.doInBackground(LoadingFragment.java:75)
        at net.xx.wildedibles.full.intro.LoadingFragment$LoadingTask.doInBackground(LoadingFragment.java:68)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
        ... 4 more
```

Line 27 of DatabaseHelper:

```
  DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString();
```

Now I know that there are several ways out there to calculate the path to the databases/, and I've tried essentially all of them, with none working. Still get the same NPE.

But here's a little curiosity: I decided to do `adb shell` and look into the app's directory structure, to get a better idea as to where I've been going wrong. Here's what I get after navigating to data/data/package.name/:

```
# cd net.xx.wildedibles.full
# ls
lib
#
```

Why can't I see /databases/, and where's all the other stuff? When I go into lib/, there's nothing inside. As you can see, I'm root while looking. Given this, I can certainly see why I'd be getting a null pointer...

Thanks so much for any advice you can offer!

As requested, here's the full code:

Here's a DBAdapter class:

```
public class DBAdapter 
{
    protected static final String TAG = "DataAdapter";

    private final Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;

    public DBAdapter(Context context) 
    {
    mContext = context;
        mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);
   }

    public DBAdapter createDatabase() throws SQLException 
    {
        try 
        {
            mDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } 
        catch (IOException mIOException) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString() + "  UnableToCreateDatabase");
            throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase");
        }
        return this;
    }

    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        try 
        {
            mDbHelper.openDataBase();
            mDbHelper.close();
            mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        } 
        catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "open >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
            throw mSQLException;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void close() 
    {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

     public Cursor getData(String query)
     {
         try
         {

             Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
             if (mCur!=null)
             {
                mCur.moveToNext();
             }
             return mCur;
         }
         catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
         {
             Log.e(TAG, "getData >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
             throw mSQLException;
         }
     }
}
```

Here's the whole of the Helper class:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; //tag for logcat
    private static String DB_PATH;
    private static String DB_NAME ="foraging.db";// Database name
    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase; 
    private final Context mContext;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context){

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 4.2){
           DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString();

        }
        else
        {
           DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        }
        this.mContext = context;
    }   

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException
    {   
        //If database does not exist, copy from assets/

        boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
      if(!mDataBaseExist)
       {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close();
            try {
                //Copy the database from assests
                copyDataBase();
                Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
        } 
        catch (IOException mIOException) 
        {
            throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
        }
    }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase()
    {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    //Copy the database from assets
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
        {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }


    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException
    {
        String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        //Log.v("mPath", mPath);
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        //mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() 
    {
        if(mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe that directory is not created. Not all the apps need a DB. You could try to create it in case it does not already exists.

Comment: I think we need to see the code that creates the db in order to help more on this

Comment: Added the two DB-handling classes so that you can see exactly what's going on. But I don't think you'll find any surprises in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database isn't created until your first call to `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWriteableDatabase()`, straight from [the horse's mouth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase()):

> public SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase()
>
> Create and/or open a database. ...

If you want your created database to be duplicated from a prebuilt one you have in your assets folder (an idea I like since you don't have to do all your `CREATE` statements in SQL in Java) you'll need to first call `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWriteableDatabase()` *then* copy the file over. An example of that can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728).

Edit: Just saw in your edit that you're using the same code I linked to. Note that the code in the answer does not call `getDatabasePath` but instead tries to make the path manually since it knows it's possible it doesn't exist.

`getDatabasePath` is throwing a NPE because as it says in [its description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)) it returns `the absolute path on the filesystem where a database created`. Your file isn't created yet!